# Cannot overwrite PDF file created with iTextsharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

Does anybody know why I cannot overwrite a PDF file created with iTextSharp.

It gives me the error:

> The process cannot access the file because it's being use

I also tried to delete the file and it's giving me the message:

> file is open in IIS Express Worker Process

Code:

```
Dim pdfDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(Path & strFileName & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))

pdfDoc.Open()

    Try
        Using sw As New StringWriter()

            Using hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

                Panel1.RenderControl(hw)

                Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())

                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)

            End Using

        End Using

        pdfDoc.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw ex

    Finally

        writer.Close()
        writer.Dispose()

    End Try
```

Comment: you put your try catch after `pdfDoc.Open()` so if you have an error you dont close it in your `Catch` so try also adding `pdfDoc.Close()` in Catch and in `Finally`

Comment: It's possible that this part of the code is responsible:  `New FileStream(Path & strFileName & ".pdf", FileMode.Create)`  You are creating a new `FileStream` instance inline and it may not be getting closed.  Try storing that in a variable and then closing it afterwards.